# Wouldn't the Scarlet Witch still be in the process of destroying the Mind Stone after Thanos turns back time?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

When Thanos uses the Time Stone to reverse time in order to get the Mind Stone from Vision, the Scarlet Witch should have still been standing in the same spot and would have been firing her energy blast into the Mind Stone.

So, why is it that she is still laying on the ground behind Thanos after he finishes reversing time and is about to take the Mind Stone from Vision?

Technically, after Thanos had reversed time, he should have immediately been hit in the back by Scarlet Witch's energy blast because he had walked over and had put himself in the space between her and Vision before he started the time reversal process.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Time Stone can be used to make just an object reverse itself.  In the Dr. Strange movie, Strange uses the stone on an apple and makes it age and return:

Comment: @ Treborcram, that's a good point.

Comment: That means it is possible to create infinite resources using the stone. Someone can eat the apple, have the food inside them and then reverse time for only the apple, creating matter.

Comment: @Parrotmaster - Well, yes. That's why it's the Infinity Gauntlet, and not the Infinitesimal Gauntlet.

Comment: @Parrotmaster Alternatively reversing time on the apple might magic the pieces in Doctor Strange's stomach back into place. It's unclear from the movie, at least, whether it can create or destroy matter; for example when Thanos snapped and wiped out half of all life, the affected people didn't just disappear, they seemed to turn into ash, so there was some 'conversion' going on rather than just 'deletion'.

Comment: @TylerH True, but there's also a lot less ash than one would expect from a full human body. And we don't know if all the stones follow the same rules. Maybe reversing entropy is what makes the time-stone a time-stone.